Hot water recirculation system options
The most common systems are Watts and Grundfos pumps with a plastic thermostatic sensor valve under the farthest sink. These valves break down every few years and are not inexpensive to replace. In homes without a dedicated return line, these systems fill too much warm water in the cold line.
Then there are under the sink systems such as ReadyTemp smart controllers such as Intelli-Circ https://readytemp.com/efficienthotwatercirculation.htm or TL4000N which integrates smart controller with the pump https://readytemp.com/tanklesshotwatercirculator.php
These cost about twice as much.
Another option is Smart Circulator https://a.co/d/jjOlETC
My goal is to avoid wasting energy and water while having at least warm water readily available.
What are your experiences and which ones do you recommend?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

My preferred approach (if I ever do this) is a dedicated return with a check valve, and a motion sensor running the pump for a fixed time. The motion sensor could be in the hallway to start the flow sooner, or in the bathroom to start the flow only when someone comes in. In a household with "aware, competent" inhabitants, a simple timer switch could be used rather than a motion sensor, but a motion sensor makes it easy even for the unaware, it's just more complicated to set up with time delay relays, etc.
I would not, at all, try to keep the loop hot at all times - it's a huge waste of heating effort, even with insulation on the pipe, since there's a lot of pipe area to lose heat from. If nobody is moving around the house, nobody needs hot water right then. If they are moving, they might.
My actual approach so far is to try and keep the waterlines short. But I see a possible case where I might need to violate that rule. And I've thought this case through. Run the pump long enough to get hot water to the far end, then stop.
